# The set of rational numbers has continuum many subsets that are order-wise inequivalent

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, rational-numbers

How to show that there are continuum many subsets of $\mathbb Q$, no two of which are similar?

Two sets are called similar if there is an order-preserving bijection between them.

Comment: What does it mean for two subsets to be similar?

Comment: If they are of the same form/shape... there is an f : $A_1$ → $A_2$ 1-to-1 correspondence between the ground sets $A_1$ and $A_2$ that also preserves the ordering

Comment: Probably a good candidate would be to consider all those sets of the form $A_\alpha = \{x \in \mathbb{Q} \mid x > \alpha\}$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. I imagine it wouldn't be too hard to show that $A_\alpha$ is similar to $A_\beta$ if and only if $\alpha +p/q =\beta$ for some rational $p/q$.

Comment: Suppose we define "similar" to mean having the same shape, i.e. one of them is an affine image of the other.  Is the conclusion still the same? (My suspicion is that it is and that that's easy to prove, and maybe it could even be used to solve this present problem.) $\qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possible ways to do this; here's one.  Given $f:\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\}$, consider the ordered set $$S_f=\mathbb{Z}+f(0)+\mathbb{Z}+f(1)+\mathbb{Z}+f(2)+\cdots$$ Here $+$ is the sum of ordered sets (like ordinal addition), and we think of the values $f(n)$ as ordered sets by letting $0$ be the empty set and $1$ be the singleton ordered set.  Then each $S_f$ is a countable totally ordered set, and it is not hard to show that $S_f\cong S_g$ iff $f=g$.  Since every countable totally ordered set embeds in $\mathbb{Q}$ (alternatively, it is easy to show directly that each $S_f$ embeds in $\mathbb{Q}$), you get continuum many dissimilar subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Or simply, for each function $g:\mathbb N\to\{\omega,\omega^*\}$, take a set of order type $g(1)+g(2)+g(3)+\cdots$?